# How to find duplicates in Schema RDD [created out of Case Class] in Spark Scala and respective duplicate counts?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, rdd

I have one Schema RDD created from Case Class. I need to find duplicate entries considering all columns and duplicate count in Spark Scala

Answer (score 0):

Since, it is a case class it will have its own hash function. You can use that to group elements.

```scala
val yourRdd: RDD[YourCaseClass] = ???

val duplicateCountRdd: RDD[(Int, Iterable[YourCaseClass])] = 
  yourRdd
    .groupBy(_.hashCode)
    .map({ case (hash, duplicates) => (duplicates.size, duplicates) })
```

Comment: Hi  @sarvesheri , am new to this Spark Scala. Could you please explain the above code. I could see its returning distinct elements.